# How to download jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am a beginer of python. After review the intalling session, I still don't get how to download the jupyter as software tool, such as pip or conda. Can anyone share the steps of how to downloading it?

Thanks

Jielan Liu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply download it by installing [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) which comes with *Jupyter Notebooks already* installed.

Comment: Thanks. I am learning Python with a tutorial required download jupyter notebooks. He mentioned anaconda but I don't know it comes with Jupyter notebooks.